# Arrange Data in a collapsible tree in html using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following data in 2 different arrays:

**Level 1**

3.0        abc

2.1        xyz

2.0        pqr

**Level 2**

3.0.0.8          abc

3.0.0.7           pqr

2.1.0.155         lmn

2.1.0.151         rst

2.0.5.16          jhw

2.0.0.96          lqs

Now I want to arrange them in a collapsible tree fashion, which would look like this:

(+) 3.0 abc

```
  - 3.0.0.8 abc

  - 3.0.0.7 pqr
```

(+) 2.1 xyz

```
  - 2.1.0.155 lmn

  - 2.1.0.151 rst
```

(+) 2.0 pqr

```
  - 2.0.5.16 jhw

  - 2.0.0.96 lqs
```

I know it can be done with Javascript and Jquery. But can someone give me some sample code or some pointers to some very basic code which I can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.com/jqTree/).

Create an array of hashes of labels (aka parents) and children by iterating through your arrays and using [substring or substr](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2159-Using-Slice-Substring-And-Substr-In-Javascript.htm) to match and merge.